# Gitlab CI/CD not triggering the job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a React app (using Create React App) that I want to deploy to Heroku.

For that I am trying to use GitLab CI/CD

Here is the code inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: node:latest

before_script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl

stages:
    - staging
    - production

staging:
    type: deploy
    stage: staging
    image: ruby:latest
    script:
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$DEV_APP_NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    only:
        - develop

production:
    type: deploy
    stage: production
    image: ruby:latest
    script:
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$STAGING_APP_NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    only:
        - master
```

I am trying to use shared runner and I have not added any specific runner. I have left the runner configuration to default as to what it was when I created my repo.

Even if I push to my repo on master or develop branch it is not triggered.

Comment: Did it ever work in this project? If not, then you could try setting up some simle pipeline first without `only` restriction to make sure that configuration is right.

Comment: @makozaki no it did not work at all. Can please give me some example of yml to make sure that it works at least.

Comment: `tests:
    script:
      - echo 123` just add proper indent

Comment: Do I have to do anything thing apart from adding yml file @makozaki

Comment: No just replace `.gitlab-ci.yml` with example script, push it to gitlab and go to **Project Page -> Ci/CD -> Pipelines** to see results.